# What are the alignment rules for a dynamic arrays in SPIR-V with std430?

Tags: vulkan, spir-v

The spec says

> [140] An array has a base alignment equal to the base alignment of its element type, rounded up to a multiple of 16.
>   .... [430] except for array and structure base alignment which do not need to be rounded up to a multiple of 16.

I assume the size for a static array is trivially `size_of(elem_type) * length` but what about a dynamic array?

There are no pointers in the logical mode, does that mean the size of a dynamic array is 0?

I don't know which offsets I should apply to the following struct

```
struct Data {
    float i1;
    float[] arr;
    float i2;
}
```

Or in SPIR-V notation

```
%Data = OpTypeStruct %float %_runtimearr_float %float
```

Can this be done, or do the same rules of GLSL apply here where you are only allowed to have exactly one dynamic array inside a buffer block, and it has to be the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vulkan, in Appendix A, defines the execution environment for SPIR-V; as such, it can impose limits on what it allows in shaders beyond that of the SPIR-V specification. In that appendix, it says:

> `OpTypeRuntimeArray` must only be used for the last member of an `OpTypeStruct` that is in the `StorageBuffer` storage class decorated as `Block`, or that is in the `Uniform` storage class decorated as `BufferBlock`.